# Table and group_by in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

```
a<-data_frame(id=c(rep("A",100),rep("B",78),rep("C",50)),
              vall=c(rep("x",100),rep("y",78),rep("x",50)),
              val=runif(228))
```

Now, I´d like to have the following output:

```
a2<-a %>% group_by(id) %>% count(vall)
table(a2$vall)
```

but, I´d prefer to have a oneliner and not having to create a2. Is there a smart way of doing this?

Comment: Why can't you keep using the pipe instead of creating `a2`? For instance `count(a, vall, id) %>% count(vall)`?

Comment: Or, if you really want to use `table`, you can do `a %>% count(vall, id) %>% {table(.$vall)}`

Comment: Very good. @DavidArenburg - I had the order inside the count mixed up and hence got the wrong output. @Axeman - I did the same, but without the  {} and got the `Error in sort.list(y)`. What is the logic of {} here?

Comment: If either one of you answer it, I´ll accept it. Your versions are more succinct than the one offered so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akruns answer is fine, but the question was for dplyr. I just pasted the alternatives from the comments section here for completeness.

```
a %>% count(vall, id) %>% {table(.$vall)}

count(a, vall, id) %>% count(vall)
```

Answer (score 3):

This gets the output you want without creating a new table or using the table function. However the output layout is slightly different:

```
library(tidyverse)
a %>% group_by(id) %>% count(vall) %>% group_by(vall) %>% count()
```

Does that help at all?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an one-liner with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)[, .N, .(id, vall)][, .N , vall]
```